# Duplicate row if a update happens

Tags: c#, hibernate, nhibernate

i have the following Trigger:

```
    INSERT INTO [BUCHUNG] (BOOKUID, BOOKVERNR, BUCHUNGSART_ID, VERANSTALTER, PERSONAL_ID,
    OPTIONSNUMMER, BUCHUNGSSTATUS, PERSONENZAHL, SERIE, THEMA, STORNO, UPDATE_DATE, UPDATE_USER, BEMERKUNG, V_EMAIL, V_TELEFON,
    KOSTENSTELLE, SERIENBOOKUID, THEMA_ENABLED, ABTEILUNG, LIEFERRAUM, PERSONENZAHLEXTERN, ABRECHNUNG, KSTR, RECHKONTO, RECHKST, RECHDST, URSPRUNG_ORIGINAL, ORIGINAL_ID)

    SELECT i.BOOKUID, '0', i.BUCHUNGSART_ID, i.VERANSTALTER, i.PERSONAL_ID,
    i.OPTIONSNUMMER, i.BUCHUNGSSTATUS, i.PERSONENZAHL, i.SERIE, i.THEMA, i.STORNO, GETDATE(), i.UPDATE_USER, i.BEMERKUNG, i.V_EMAIL, i.V_TELEFON,
    i.KOSTENSTELLE, i.SERIENBOOKUID, i.THEMA_ENABLED, i.ABTEILUNG, i.LIEFERRAUM, i.PERSONENZAHLEXTERN, i.ABRECHNUNG, i.KSTR, i.RECHKONTO, i.RECHKST, i.RECHDST, i.URSPRUNG_ORIGINAL,
    i.ORIGINAL_ID


    FROM INSERTED i
    JOIN DELETED d ON i.ID = d.ID
    WHERE i.BOOKVERNR <> d.BOOKVERNR
```

The Trigger duplicate the entire row with a new ID if a update on BOOKVERNR happens. My Question is how can i do that in hibernate? I dont want to use a Database Trigger. I want to do that directly in C# with hibernate. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at NHibernate's event system, or possibly the older IInterceptor concept:
http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#events

Using a suitable event handler, you should be able to detect when an update is about to happen, and in that case insert a row with the old information.